# Uniform convergence of convex continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f_n\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous convex non-decreasing functions for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f_n\to f$ pointwise. I want to prove that the convergence is uniform in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

At first I wanted to use Dini's theorem but $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not compact. I understand that convexity is the key property here. Are there any other well known theorems that use convexity, in order to get rid of compactness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is not true. Consider the following example in one dimension, that can be easily adapted to 3-dimensional space:
$$
f_n(x)=\frac1n\,e^x.
$$
Each $f_n$ is increasing, convex and continuous. $f_n$ converges pointwise but not uniformly to $0$.